# What is the optimal method for getting every Unown in the Ruins of Alph?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

In the [Ruins of Alph](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ruins_of_Alph) in the Johto region, you can introduce four groups of the [Unown](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Unown_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) alphabet to the main chamber in whatever order you'd like. Each group is a different size.

If I wanted to capture every Unown letter as fast as possible, what is the optimal order for introducing and encountering Unown, and why?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### *Introduce every group, then start catching.*

Learned myself a new mathematical concept.

This question is a variation on the [Coupon Collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem): "Given n coupons, how many coupons do you expect you need to draw with replacement before having drawn each coupon at least once?" the simplified solution being:

E(T) = n * H<sub>n - k</sub>

Where E(T) is the estimated number of draws required, n is the number of unique coupons there are, k is the number of unique coupons you've already drawn before starting the trial, and H<sub>n - k</sub> being the (n - k)th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

So, if we introduce the smallest group of Unown first, catch them all, then introduce the next smallest and so forth, the expected number of encounters looks like this:

E(T) = 3 * H<sub>3</sub> + 8 * H<sub>5</sub> + 15 * H<sub>7</sub> + 26 * H<sub>11</sub> = **141.176**

Contrasting introducing the largest group first and going smaller and smaller, we get:

E(T) = 11 * H<sub>11</sub> + 18 * H<sub>7</sub> + 23 * H<sub>5</sub> + 26 * H<sub>3</sub> = **180.073**

Finally, let's look at releasing all the Unown at once and then starting the hunt:

E(T) = 26 * H<sub>26</sub> = **100.215**

So as it would turn out, releasing all the Unown at once is far and away the best solution.

I wasn't factoring in Unown Z's reduced spawn rate in the calculation, so it may be worthwhile (for peace of mind if nothing else) to get X, Y and Z first anyway.

Comment: Oh nice, I figured there was probably a mathematical/statistical solution, very interesting that releasing all at once is most optimal. Well done! :)

Comment: If you go with the strategy of releasing X, Y, and Z first, collect all three, then release everything else, the result assuming even spawn chance is 102.592, only marginally worse than releasing everything at once, so I suspect that it is indeed worthwhile to use such an approach simply to avoid the possibility of a long tail of trying to catch Z.

Answer (score 4):

It could be easier in some cases to complete the Ho-oh puzzle first. While it may be the slightly [statistically worse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/404914/what-is-the-optimal-method-for-getting-every-unown-in-the-ruins-of-alph#comment568533_404916) option, completing that puzzle releases Unown X,Y and Z, and Unown Z [has a lower chance to appear](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ruins_of_Alph#Inside) due to the way the Unown form is determined in an encounter.

It would therefore make sense to hunt for Z when you have less Unown released, giving you a greater chance of encountering it.

Incidentally, here is the list of each Unown released when a puzzle is completed:

- **Kabuto** - unlocks 11 letters - A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K
- **Omanyte** - unlocks 7 letters - L, M, N, O, P, Q, R
- **Aerodactyl** - unlocks 5 letters -  S, T, U, V, W
- **Ho-oh** - unlocks 3 letters - X, Y, Z